# Maven, QUerysdl and intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, querydsl

I used querysdl on a springboot project.
I have a strange bheaviour.
When i try to use 'mvn clean install' command the query class are generated, but i get an error like

[ERROR] Attempt to recreate a file for type it.mypackage.db.entity.accessory.QShipmentCostType

if i try to use eclipse configuration to run the project i get the same message and the execution end with error.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <id>generate-query-class</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include> it.mypackage.db.entity.** </include>
                        </includes>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

i use Spring boot 3; Hibernate 6 and java 17

Comment: This is reported an issue, and there is a possible solution on comments. See https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/3431.